# How can a null pointer change its value?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I used something like this:

```
struct Node
{
    char name[50];
    Node *left,*right;
};

int main()
{
    char cmd[10];
    Node* p=NULL;

    scanf("%s",&cmd);

    if (p == NULL)
    {
        // do something

        // THIS NEVER GETS EXECUTED
        // WHYYYYY????
        //THIS IS STRANGE
    }
}
```

So basically, the pointer `p` changes its value after I read into the `cmd` variable. I tried to commented out the `scanf` code, and then everything works. Very strange.

Comment: _warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[10]' [-Wformat]_ - Turn on warnings.

Comment: Perhaps even more important, what was the input? Did it fit in `char[10]`?

Comment: Did you leave it on the bedpost overnight?

Comment: Using `scanf("%s"` to read strings without any width limit is as bad as using `gets` function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a buffer overflow.

The memory looks like this:

```
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
 ^                             ^
 cmd[10]                       p
```

If scanf reads more than 10 bytes, it will overflow to `p`. Any non-zero value will fail the NULL check, even if it is not a valid pointer.

Comment: Note: this is happenstance for a particular implementation - other systems, or even other runs of the same program might do something different

Comment: I wanted it to look as simple as possible. I left outside any alignment, padding or pointer size issues.